# How to display URL as a text on PDF

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display some URL on PDF (Rendered as PDF), but my URL displaying as a link type text, means if i do mouse over on that URL content its showing the hand symbol and user can able to clickable that text, but i want to display this a just text not a clickable text. My sample code is in below

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" >  
  <apex:form >
      <apex:outputLabel value="URL :  "/> 
      <apex:outputText value="www.salesforce.com" />
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please advise me how i can solve this

Thanks
Surendra

Comment: don't make it as link . add is as a simple text using apex:outputText

Comment: Thanks for reply,Please find my code in below
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" >  
  <apex:form >
      <apex:outputLabel value="URL :  "/> 
      <apex:outputText value="www.salesforce.com" />
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact requirement, but you can do this with a little html trick. Divide the URL into two parts, wrap one part in a span tag. Put a space between them so that it will not render as URL then put a negative margin to bring the two words closer to remove the space. Here is the modified code.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputLabel value="URL : "/>
        <apex:outputText value="www. <span style=margin-left:-3px;>salesforce.com</span>" escape="false"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: My requirement is not a hard coded way, it will be dynamic, we are using some database text field to display the URL PDF
<apex:form >
      <apex:outputLabel value="URL :  "/> 
      <apex:outputText value="{!companyURL__c}" />
  </apex:form>
Through your solution, URL will get space next of " www.", we don't want to show that actually